# Torrents won't download normally on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, bittorrent

By not normally I mean that they will download with 100-200kb/s (max on my net is 1mb/s) for a few seconds, then 0kb/s and so on, always. I've used both Deluge and Transmission with no luck. I want to point out that on the same computer, on Windows 8, the same torrent downloads perfectly . I've changed ports a bit, put maximum upload limits, slots, attempts to connect but there is no improvement. I have no idea what is wrong!